# Change UI tab according to URL pattern

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, tabs, jquery-tabs

I am using Jquery Ui tabs framework.I want to change the selected tab accoring to URL pattern in the browser such as www.xyz.com/#tab1 or  www.xyz.com/#tab2.

I found a workaround using

```
$("#tabs").bind('tabsselect', function(event, ui) {
                window.location.href=ui.tab;
```

However, it is making the tab anchor selected but is not actually changing the tab and i have to press the enter key to actually change the tab. Can someone point where i am wrong and can hint changes so that the tab changes accoring to URL pattern.

I am using the following code to implement this

```
 $(document).ready(function() {




   $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
         beforeLoad: function( event, ui )
          {        
          ui.jqXHR.error(function() { 
                   ui.panel.html(            "Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible. "  ); 
                          }); 
                               }    
                               });

            $("#tabs").bind('tabsselect', function(event, ui) {
            window.location.href=ui.tab;

        });

 });
```

HTML code

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
    <li><strong class="first">
    <a href="#tabs1" id="tab1">Tab-1</a>
    </strong></li>
<li>
<strong>
<a href="xyz.do" id="tab2">Tab-2</a>
</strong>
</li>

</ul>

<div id="tabs1">
tab -1 content
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want to bind via the activate handler. 
http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-activate

```
$( ".selector" ).on( "tabsactivate", function( event, ui ) { changeColor(ui); } );
```

ui.tab will have the details about the tab that was clicked.

In your case I think you will want to say

```
    var changeColor(ui) = function(
    if (ui.index == 1) { 
       $("#selector").addClass("tab2Active"); 
    });
```